# Pandas: Sort the row counts per group in ascending order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting

I have a `df` as below:

```
In [257]: df
Out[257]: 
   user_id col1       col2
0        1    A    4.00000
1        1    A   22.00000
2        1    A  112.00000
3        1    B   -0.22222
4        1    B    9.00000
5        1    C    0.00000
6        2    A   -1.00000
7        2    A   -5.00000
8        2    K        NaN
```

I calculate the row counts per group using `Groupby.size`:

```
In [258]: df.groupby(['user_id', 'col1'])['col2'].size()
Out[258]: 
user_id  col1
1        A       3
         B       2
         C       1
2        A       2
         K       1
Name: col2, dtype: int64
```

Currently, the output above is in `desc` order. Is there a pandaic way to get the output in `asc` order?

**Expected Output:**

```
user_id  col1
1        C       1
         B       2
         A       3
2        K       1
         A       2
```

Comment: Why not sort the dataframe before grouping?

Comment: That won't work as I don't want to sort on any existing column. I want to sort on the output of `Groupby.size`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need sorting by first level with values of `Series`, here is solution with one column `DataFrame` and [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for sorting by first level `user_id` with `col2`, last for `Series` select `col2`:

```
s = df.groupby(['user_id', 'col1'])['col2'].size()

s = s.to_frame().sort_values(['user_id', 'col2'])['col2']
print (s)
user_id  col1
1        C       1
         B       2
         A       3
2        K       1
         A       2
Name: col2, dtype: int64
```

Another idea with `groupby`, if larger DataFrame should be slowier:

```
s = df.groupby(['user_id', 'col1'])['col2'].size()

s = s.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values())
print (s)
user_id  col1
1        C       1
         B       2
         A       3
2        K       1
         A       2
Name: col2, dtype: int64
```

Comment: What is `s` here?

Comment: `s = df.groupby(['user_id', 'col1'])['col2'].size()`

Answer (score 2):

The closest I have come is;

```
df.groupby(['user_id', 'col1'])['col2'].size().to_frame().sort_index(ascending=False)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this working only in sample data, generaly not, because not sorting by counts, only by `MultiiIndex`

Comment: You can see it if replace e.g. `C` with `A` and `A` with `C` in sample data, then solution failed.